# Apply automatically a coupon based on specific cart items count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I am trying to automatically trigger a coupon to be applied in the cart specifically for when there are 4 items in the cart.

The coupon is pre-created in the Woocommerce back-end of the site *"tasterbox"*

I am using an amended version from this answer code: 
[Add WooCommerce coupon code automatically based on product categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272782/add-woocommerce-coupon-code-automatically-based-on-product-categories/45273170#45273170)

Here is my code version:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'wc_auto_add_coupons', 10, 1 );
function wc_auto_add_coupons( $cart_object ) {

    // Coupon code
    $coupon = 'tasterbox';

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Initialising variables
    $is_match = false;
    $taster_item_count = 4;

    //  Iterating through each cart item
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // If cart items match 4
        if( $cart->cart_contents_count == $taster_item_count ){
            $is_match = true; // Set to true
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }

    // If conditions are matched add the coupon discount
    if( $is_match && ! $cart_object->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Apply the coupon code
        $cart_object->add_discount( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message 
        wc_add_notice( __('TASTER BOX ADDED'), 'notice');
    } 
    // If conditions are not matched and coupon has been appied
    elseif( ! $has_category && $cart_object->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Remove the coupon code
        $cart_object->remove_coupon( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message 
        wc_add_notice( __('SORRY, TASTERBOX NOT VALID'), 'alert');
    }
}
```

However I can not get it to auto apply the coupon when there are 4 items in the cart. It seems like something simple to do, but I'm stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some little mistakes and errors in your code. Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_add_coupon_based_on_cart_items_count', 25, 1 );
function auto_add_coupon_based_on_cart_items_count( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Setting and initialising variables
    $coupon = 'tasterbox'; // <===  Coupon code
    $item_count = 4; // <===  <===  Number of items
    $matched    = false;

    if( $cart->cart_contents_count >= $item_count ){
        $matched = true; // Set to true
    }

    // If conditions are matched add coupon is not applied
    if( $matched && ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Apply the coupon code
        $cart->add_discount( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message
        wc_add_notice( __('TASTER BOX ADDED'), 'notice');
    }
    // If conditions are not matched and coupon has been appied
    elseif( ! $matched && $cart->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Remove the coupon code
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message
        wc_add_notice( __('SORRY, TASTERBOX NOT VALID'), 'error');
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! I see the errors now. Works perfectly. This might be another question, but do you know if it's possible to hide the default Woocommerce `coupon_applied_successfully` alert for only this auto apply coupon?