# Disable tax calculation on a discount using the Fee Api in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I am using a custom fee to calculate a discount based on amount of items in cart. 
Discount becomes more if there are more products in the cart.

Discount should be €5 for 2 products, but is €6,05 because 21% tax gets calculated over the discount amount.

The code i'am using is the following

```
    // Hook before calculate fees
    add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

    /**
    * Add custom fee bij meer dan 2 artikelen
    * @param WC_Cart $cart
    */
    function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    if( $cart->cart_contents_count < 2 ){
    return;
}

//$Korting = Winkelwagen geteld * 5) - 5 (-5 is om eerste product korting te verwijderen;
// Calculate the amount to reduce
$discount = ($cart->get_cart_contents_count() * 5) -5;
$cart->add_fee( 'Sinterklaaskorting', -$discount, false);
}
```

Can someone help to get the tax out of the fee.

Answer (score 0):

**The Fee API can be tweaked to make a discount using a negative fee**, just as your code does.

> But in that case **the taxes are always applied** when using a negative amount, so the third argument **`$taxable`** in [`WC_Cart` `add_fees()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1703-1723) **is always true** even if you set it to false.
>   See: [Apply a discount on the cart content total excluding taxes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802738/apply-a-discount-on-the-cart-content-total-excluding-taxes-in-woocommerce)

There is no turn around for this case, as the `WC_Cart` Fee API is made for fee but not for discount.

You could use: [Apply automatically a coupon based on specific cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358992/apply-automatically-a-coupon-based-on-specific-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce) 
 with a percentage discount, **but the taxes are also applied when using coupons.**

So there is no way to get a discount without removing taxes at the same time.