# Auto apply coupon based on total spent in shop woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I need to apply a previously created coupon in woocommerce cart based on total spent in shop by logged in users. Example, If user already spent $300 or more in previous orders, in the next order, automatically apply "xxx" coupon.

based on *"[Apply automatically a coupon based on specific cart items count in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358992/apply-automatically-a-coupon-based-on-specific-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce/52359468#52359468)"* answer thread, that is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_add_coupon_based_on_cart_items_count', 25, 1 );
function auto_add_coupon_based_on_cart_items_count( $user_id, $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Setting and initialising variables
    $coupon = 'descuentolealtad'; // <===  Coupon code
    $matched = false;
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

    if( $customer->get_total_spent >= 60 ){
        $matched = true; // Set to true
    }

    // If conditions are matched add coupon is not applied
    if( $matched && ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Apply the coupon code
        $cart->add_discount( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message
        wc_add_notice( __('Descuento de Lealtad aplicado'), 'notice');
    }
    // If conditions are not matched and coupon has been appied
    elseif( ! $matched && $cart->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Remove the coupon code
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message
        //wc_add_notice( __('Descuento de Lealtad removido'), 'error');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the dedicated `get_total_spent()` function from woocommerce but is giving me a blank screen.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Edit**

That is my working code very different as I am using a negative fee:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'discount_based_on_customer_orders', 10, 1);
function discount_based_on_customer_orders( $cart_object ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;  
    // Getting "completed" customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );
    // Orders count
    $customer_orders_count = count($customer_orders);
    // The cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_total(); // or WC()->cart->get_total_ex_tax()

    // First customer order discount
    if( empty($customer_orders) || $customer_orders_count == 0 ){
        $discount_text = __('Loyalty Discount', 'woocommerce');
        $discount = -7;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** - There is many mistakes in your code like:

- For this hook there is only one variable argument: `$cart`… and not `$user_id` and `$cart`
- Since Woocommerce 3, use the method `get_total_spent()` and not the property `get_total_spent`.
- You should first check that user is logged in too.

Use the following revisited code instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'auto_add_coupon_based_on_total_spent', 10, 1 );
function auto_add_coupon_based_on_total_spent( $cart ) {

    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) || ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Setting and initialising variables
    $coupon = 'summer'; // <===  Coupon code
    $spent_amount = 60;

    $customer = new WC_Customer(get_current_user_id());

    // If conditions are matched add coupon is not applied
    if( $customer->get_total_spent() >= $spent_amount && ! $cart->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Apply the coupon code
        $cart->add_discount( $coupon );

        // Optionally display a message
        wc_add_notice( __('Descuento de Lealtad aplicado'), 'notice');
    }
    // If conditions are not matched and coupon has been appied
    elseif($customer->get_total_spent() < $spent_amount && $cart->has_discount( $coupon )){
        // Remove the coupon code
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better works.

Comment: I've edited my original question to update my code and suggest a different approach. Thanks. @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec .  The code attempts to add the coupon and the "Coupon Added" Message appears in cart. But neither the coupon itself nor the discount is shown/applied on the cart.

Comment: Now is working man. I understand. This gets tiresome. Thanks for the help @LoicTheAztec.